# Understanding spaced repetition algorithm

Tags: algorithms, computer-science, education

I would like to understand [this spaced repetition algorithm](https://www.supermemo.com/english/algsm11.htm#3078-16), but it looks very mathematical to me -which is not my field at all. However, I would like to dive into it.

My question: What are the concepts involved in this algorithm that I would need to study, before I can understand it? I am *not* looking for a shopping list or book recommendations, but just the areas & subjects areas you think I should cover in order to tackle this algorithm. What's involved there?

Also, do let me know if you think this is a very complex endeavour, or if, quite the opposite, I could maybe just sit down with a mathematician who can explain this to me in plain English - I have no idea if it actually is as complex as it looks like to me, a complete beginner.

PS: Being a beginner, i am not entirely sure what to tag here, if somebody could help me out that would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: You may find more luck on [psychology.se]. For starter: [Compared efficiency of different spaced-repetition memorisation techniques](https://psychology.stackexchange.com/q/1038/12937)